# Print binary tree using different keys

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree

I have this structure c code for a tree:

```
typedef struct product{
    char name[50];
    char id[5];
    double price;
    int amount;
    struct product *left_p, *right_p;
}product_t;
```

I use the id to insert/remove/print the records, but I also need to print them in order of the name, price or amount.

I thought to copy the tree to an array then order the array or make a new tree with a new key and delete the old one, but I don't think the last one is a good solution, considering that I only need to print the records and not do operations on them. Do you think the first solution is nice or do you have some tips on how I can handle this ?

I have to use a tree because the exercise I'm working on requires it.

Comment: Please post the solution you were working on.

Comment: Your solution looks OK to me, but you shouldn't have an array of `product_t` but an array of pointers to `product_t`. Sorting the array is easy with `qsort`.

Comment: First thing you do when designing a data structure is to define the operations on it and the desired complexity of each (printing is an operation too). Who said you need a tree at all?

Comment: This could also be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). In other words: what are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: 1) Traverse to to find size.  2) allocate memory of pointers to node 3) traverse tree again and copy node address to the array elements. 4) Sort array `qsort()`.  5) print 6) free allocation.